# Page fails to load when automating using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am new to both Selenium and Python. I want to scrape some information from a the travel website airCanada.ca using Selenium, Python, Chrome Browser and Chrome Driver. When I tried to load a sample page using Selenium, the page simply hangs forever and never loads. When I copy the same URL into the browser directly, the page loads without any problem. I have tried similar loading some other travel websites, such as Kayak, but there were no problems loading these pages. There may be an obvious solution but I don't know what the next step would be. Below is a sample code fragment:

```
SAMPLE_URL = "https://www.aircanada.com/aeroplan/redeem/availability/outbound?org0=YTO&dest0=LGA&departureDate0=2023-11-01&lang=en-CA&tripType=O&ADT=1&YTH=0&CHD=0&INF=0&INS=0&marketCode=TNB"

os.environ['PATH'] +=r";C:/SeleniumDrivers/chromedriver-win64/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get(SAMPLE_URL)
time.sleep(20)
```

Both my browser and driver are up to date. I have also tried using Microsoft Edge Browser and driver, but I encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This site contains anti-scrapping mechanism.

To pass it you can try to use `Undetected Chromedriver`.

It's a driver that can bypass most of anti-scrapping approaches, like Cloudflare, etc.

[Reference](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

SAMPLE_URL="https://www.aircanada.com/aeroplan/redeem/availability/outbound?org0=YTO&dest0=LGA&departureDate0=2023-11-01&lang=en-CA&tripType=O&ADT=1&YTH=0&CHD=0&INF=0&INS=0&marketCode=TNB"

driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get(SAMPLE_URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase in `uc` mode to bypass the anti-selenium script on the website.

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
try:
    driver.get("https://www.aircanada.com/aeroplan/redeem/availability/outbound?org0=YTO&dest0=LGA&departureDate0=2023-11-01&lang=en-CA&tripType=O&ADT=1&YTH=0&CHD=0&INF=0&INS=0&marketCode=TNB")
    driver.click('span[aria-label="Close"]', timeout=15)
    print(driver.get_text("kilo-upsell-cont"))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

It'll close the pop-up, and then print out the detailed flight search details. (Note that the seleniumbase `driver` has more methods than the standard selenium `driver`)